# Regex to capture dates that appear after certain keywords

Tags: regex

I have a series of text files that I need to process, with content like this:

> Bla bla data base: 07/08/2014 Data para pagamento do rendimento:
>   14/08/2014 Valor distribuído por cota: R$ 0,83.

I need to capture the dates in the files, but I also need to qualify the dates that I find. For example, after the keyword "base", if there is a date, I'd like to capture it (the first date found after the word "base"). Between the word "base" and the date there can be a number of other words or characters.

The dates can be in format d/M/yyyy or dd/MM/yyyy.

I'm trying the following Regex pattern:

```
"base.+(?<date>[0123]?[0-9]/[01]?[0-9]/[12]?[90]?[0-9][0-9])"
```

But I'm not getting the correct results.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "qualify"? "Validate"? Then use a simple `base:\s*\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/(?:\d{4}|\d{2})` regex and then use the `DateTime.TryParseExact` (C#, use equivalent in your programming language) to check the format.

Comment: If the format is always `: [date]`, and the date is 8 - 10 characters (0 - 9 and /), you could try this: `\: ([\d\/]{8,10}) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  the no greedy version.

`base.+?([0123]?[0-9]/[01]?[0-9]/[12]?[90]?[0-9][0-9])`

Comment: Just a remark: this will only match if `base` is on the same line with the date (if it is not Qt QRegExp).